# spinner data from database onitemselectedlistener does not working

Tags: android, android-activity, spinner, android-sqlite

when click a spinner data from database then it shows some text.But i couldn't achieve that.Spinner data added successfully into the spinner by using database.
Here is my java class file.I have an error in onItemSelected listener coding.pls tell me how to solve this.
Main Activity:

```
package com.samir.spinner;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public abstract class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
        OnItemSelectedListener {

    private EditText edittext;
    private Button btnAdd;
    private Spinner spinner;
    DatabaseHelper db;
    List<String> list;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    TextView tv;
    Set<String> s;
    protected Cursor c;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        db = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);

        edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnadd);
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        String name = edittext.getText().toString().trim();

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) {
            // showToast("Please Enter Your Name");
            edittext.setError("Please Enter Your Name");
            edittext.requestFocus();
        } else {
            db.insertData(name);
            edittext.setText("");

            // Hiding the keyboard
            InputMethodManager inputmangager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputmangager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edittext.getWindowToken(), 0);

            loadSpinner();
        }

    }

    private void loadSpinner() {
        // here i used Set Because Set doesn't allow duplicates.
        Set<String> set = db.getAllData();

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(set);

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);

        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setWillNotDraw(false);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long id) {

              Object item=parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
              tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
              tv.setText((CharSequence) item);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });
    }
}
```

Here is my logcat output:
LOGCAT:

```
08-05 08:34:51.647: E/AndroidRuntime(1586): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-05 08:34:51.647: E/AndroidRuntime(1586): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.samir.spinner/com.samir.spinner.MainActivity}: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.samir.spinner.MainActivity
08-05 08:34:51.647: E/AndroidRuntime(1586):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
08-05 08:34:51.647: E/AndroidRuntime(1586):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
08-05 08:34:51.647: E/AndroidRuntime(1586):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-05 08:34:51.647: E/AndroidRuntime(1586):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
08-05 08:34:51.647: E/AndroidRuntime(1586):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-05 08:34:51.647: E/AndroidRuntime(1586):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-05 08:34:51.647: E/AndroidRuntime(1586):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-05 08:34:51.647: E/AndroidRuntime(1586):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-05 08:34:51.647: E/AndroidRuntime(1586):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-05 08:34:51.647: E/AndroidRuntime(1586):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-05 08:34:51.647: E/AndroidRuntime(1586):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-05 08:34:51.647: E/AndroidRuntime(1586):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-05 08:34:51.647: E/AndroidRuntime(1586): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.samir.spinner.MainActivity
08-05 08:34:51.647: E/AndroidRuntime(1586):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
08-05 08:34:51.647: E/AndroidRuntime(1586):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
08-05 08:34:51.647: E/AndroidRuntime(1586):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
08-05 08:34:51.647: E/AndroidRuntime(1586):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
08-05 08:34:51.647: E/AndroidRuntime(1586):     ... 11 more
08-05 08:37:09.820: I/Process(1586): Sending signal. PID: 1586 SIG: 9
```

Here is my DatabaseHelper class.
DatabaseHelper.java:

```
package com.samir.spinner;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DB_NAME = "mydb";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "mytable";
    private static final String _id = "_id";
    private static final String name = "name";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String createTableQuery = "create table " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + _id
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + name + " TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(createTableQuery);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        db.execSQL("drop table if exists " + TABLE_NAME);

        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void insertData(String label) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(name, label);
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        db.close();
    }


    public Set<String> getAllData() {
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();

        String selectQuery = "select * from " + TABLE_NAME;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                set.add(cursor.getString(1));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        return set;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the spinner's onitemselected listener to the "this" context. That doesn't work at all, it's an invalid argument. Try this:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Object item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    }
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }
});
```

EDIT: Based on the comments below, I think your error might be here:

```
tv.setText((CharSequence) item);
```

Try doing item.getText().toString(). If that doesn't work, omit the getText() and just do toString(). I don't know for sure, though.

Comment: he is doing right. There are different forms for calling onitemclick.

Comment: I don't know for sure, so that might be true, but he says he has an error in the code at the onitemselectedlistener, and this is the way that I've done it, which works.

Comment: both methods works. actually he is not receiving onclicked item in correct form. that's y he is getting "InstantiationException"

Answer (score 0):

change

```
Object item=parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

from

```
String item = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

and simply write

```
tv.setText(item); rather then 


tv.setText((CharSequence) item);
```

Comment: Now i got following emulator output:                                    In emulator application process is waiting then emulator close

Comment: where is logcat output...??

Comment: you getting data in spinner.?? or error comes when activity starts??

Comment: then it is not the problem of onitemselected listener. there is some other issue. try to figure it out.